# Changes between two consecutive calls to Microsoft Graph API are not taken into account

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am not sure if the title represent exactely my issue, but I would explain bellow for a better undestanting.

I am using 1.17.0 microsoft-graph version(Published data: Friday, August 16, 2019 (8/16/2019)) for a mechanism to retrieve/send events from/to Office365/Outlook calendar to/from my Web application. AS a programming language I am using C#(by doing HTTP request to the Microsoft Graph API).

Actually I have a Window Service that runs at every 2 minutes and make calls to the Microsoft Graph API based on a **deltalink**. The deltalink is used to keep traking between two requests. So, after 2 minutes the service make a call and tells to the Graph API "give me all the changes made on the events for a specific calendar from the last sync".

In my web app I have an entity linked to the event from the calendar. If a change is made on the event in the calendar, I want to make the change also on my entity. I want to keep a sync between that 2 entities(the calendar event and the entity form my web app). 
For example: if I create the entity in my app, an event will be created in the calendar. If I delete the entity from my app, the event will be deleted too, and vice-versa. If I create an event from the calendar, it will be imported in my app...

My issue is as follow. 
If I made an entity in my web app, the event is created into the calendar and everything is good. But if I immeadiately delete the event from the calendar, it won't affect the entity from my web app. Because the events is added and immediately deleted(between two synchronization), it seems that this situation is not treated as an action in the calendar, and no data is sent back to my service.

If the event is created and then deleted, it is as if nothing had happened.

If I want to make this mechanism work, I have to wait to be finished a sync, so I have to wait 2 minutes until the service run again, and after that delete the event in order to make the changes on my entity.

If there is someone who has an idea how could I handle this situation in order to know when the event is created and immediately deleted I will be grateful.
So, any advice could help. Thank you!

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use Delta to do this. You could always use Change Notifications delivered by a webhook that can call your Web API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks

In this scenario you can subscribe to create and delete events and the webhook will fire and let you know. You may find depending on the amount of events being created that this is more optimal than polling every 2 minutes.